# OpenId Connect Authorization Code flow in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, openid-connect, implicit-flow

I am looking for best approach to implement the Open Id Authorization Code flow in Angular JS. Have got examples on Implicit flow to get the temporary tokens: id_token and access_token, but i need to get the long-lived token : refresh token.
Looks like I need to go for authorization code flow, where i would get the "code" based on the user credentials, and thereby using that "code" would get the refresh_token.

Ours is Angular/ Web API project(not using MVC).
Is it recommended to use authorization code flow at client side?
if so, what is the best approach/ best library that we can achieve this use case?

Answer (score 0):

keep in mind that the implicit flow is the recommended one for SPA application like angular, because it's better to send and access_token with a short lifetime rather than sending a a long lifetime token that can be used easily to generate access_tokens. but if you insist you can use the Hybrid flow, authorization code flow is more for server to server communication :

[image]